# When should I call AutoResizeColumns for a virtual ListView?

Tags: listview, autoresize, virtualmode

I'm setting up a virtual `ListView` in details mode, and I'd like its columns to automatically resize so as to not truncate the text of the currently visible items.

Calling `AutoResizeColumns` works great (at least it looks like it does, since the documentation is rather unclear on what happens in this function in virtual mode); similarly, double-clicking the column header works correctly.

What I don't know, however, is *when* to call the `AutoResizeColumns` method: at the end of the `RetrieveVirtualItem` event handler doesn't work, since calling `AutoResizeColumns` also triggers a `Refresh` of the ListView.

Could you give me a few pointers?

Comment: Did you found solution?